# Create e-mail reply with submitted data

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a Contact Form that is filled out on a `Domino` Server. Once the form is submitted, I want to send an automated reply to the user, confirming receipt.

I want to create the reply using `LotusScript`, pulling certain data from the submitted form, such as email address, contact name.

Can someone advise how I get the value of the `ContactName` / `EmailAddress` (instead of test@gmail.com) fields for the submitted document and use them to build the reply email? I have got this far with my limited knowledge of `LotusScript`:

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim Session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim email As NotesDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set email = db.CreateDocument
    email.form="Memo"
    email.principal="noreply@test.com@test"
    email.from="noreply@test.com"
    email.inetfrom="noreply@test.com"
    email.subject="Email Confirmation"
    email.body="Dear ..."
    Call email.Send(False,"test@gmail.com")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If your code goes into an agent, and the agent, then you can get the current document from UnprocessedDocuments- Property:

```
Dim dc as NotesDocumentCollection

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument
```

If the code is called from any form- event, then usually you have a Source as NotesUIDocument, if not you can get it from open document:

```
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc as NotesUIDocument

Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Set doc = uidoc.Document

'- alternative, if from event in open document, 
'- where Source is always a Parameter of type NotesUIDocument
Set doc = Source.Document
```

After that you can get values from the document by their item names:

```
strMailAddress = doc.GetitemValue( "EmailAddress" )(0)
strContactName = doc.GetitemValue( "ContactName" )(0)

email.SendTo = strMailAddress
email.Body = "Dear " & strContactName & ", asfdsdfds"
```

The UnprocessedDocument- Collection is defined by the agent properties. If it is „all new documents, then it will contain all documents that are new since last run.

You cycle through the collection by wrapping your code in a while loop:

```
Set doc = dc.Getfirstdocument
while not doc is nothing
  'Your old code goes here
  Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend
```

Comment: I have added in the Unprocessed Docs property along with the GetitemValues and it the agent works great. However, how do i deal with a series of documents ? For example, say 5 people submit forms, prior to the agent running. How would I process all of the unprocess documents in the document collection ?

Comment: Are these forms being submitted through a browser or a Notes client?